# Checkin a single file into an Azure Repo using the commandline

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-repos

I have an existing Azure Repo. What I'd like to do is checkin a single file into the Repo from a local folder, using the commandline.

I'm not particularly concerned whether this is achieved using Az Powershell, Az Cli, Git or any other scripting language for that matter, although I must say that of the named three, I'm least familiar with Git and so Az Powershell or Az Cli would probably be my preferred option.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the context? Explain why you have to use a cli to perform a commit/push.

Comment: "checkin" is for TFVC, do you using Git or TFVC?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, pay less heed to the terminology which may differ across version control systems, but the concept is essentially the same. The task is simply to add/put/commit/checkin a file into my Azure Repo (Git).

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori the task is to be automated, hence the need for a script or command.

Comment: if it's git so use command line with `git` commands, if it's TFVC so use command line with `tf.exe` commands.

Comment: Azure Repos are Git Repositories. Therefore use Git commands. What have you tried and what were the results? @LorenzoIsidori answer will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an automated way to do a commit/push you can reach it in many ways, but the commands are the same whatever cli you are using. This because every cli at the end use git :

```
git add <fileName>
git commit -m"Commit description"
git push
```

You can put those instructions in a .bat, in a .ps1 or others. Add this file in your repository and then you can execute it in the Azure Pipeline to automate this action.